# Run custom shell script added to macOS application

Tags: swift, macos, shell

How can I run my own shell script?
I know I can run system's or user's scripts using NSTask and NSPipe.
But how can I run my own script, that was added to target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, when I've added .sh file to application target it had appeared it Resources folder in build. So you can run your own script like this.
**This will work only for non sandboxed applications.**

```
var output: [String] = []
var error: [String] = []

let task = Process()
var scriptPath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
scriptPath.append("/Contents/Resources/YourScript.sh")
task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
task.arguments = [scriptPath]

let outpipe = Pipe()
task.standardOutput = outpipe
let errpipe = Pipe()
task.standardError = errpipe

task.launch()
```

Comment: just saying in case: for non sandbox app only :)

Comment: @Daij-Djan Yes thanks, you're right, added to answer =)